# How can I create DIV "rows" while having a DIV float beside them?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make one large DIV that floats to the left of my content and then use additional DIVs that are rows beside the content.

How would I do that and be sure that each "row" div is actually a row, but still respect the larger DIV on the left (the first few should not pop down below it).

I duplicated the problem on jsFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Dracorat/Xf9Qv/1/

CSS:

```
.DropCapImage {
    border: 2px solid purple;
    color: #EEE;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.DialogAction {
    padding: 10px;
    font-style: italic;
    float: left;
    clear: right;
}

.DialogLine {
    float: left;
    clear: right
}

.DialogWho {
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}

.DialogWhat {
    float: left;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    font-family: 'consolas', monospace;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="DropCapImage">Pretty Image Here</div>

<div class="DialogLine">
    <div class="DialogWho">KING CLAUDIUS</div>
    <div class="DialogWhat">Short Text</div>
</div>

    <div class="DialogAction">Exeunt all but HAMLET</div>

    <div class="DialogAction">Something Else</div>

    <div class="DialogAction">Another Else</div>

    <div class="DialogLine">
        <div class="DialogWho">HAMLET</div>
        <div class="DialogWhat">O, that this too too solid flesh would melt
Thaw and resolve itself into a dew!
Or that the Everlasting had not fix'd
His canon 'gainst self-slaughter! O God! God!
How weary, stale, flat and unprofitable,
Seem to me all the uses of this world!
Fie on't! ah fie! 'tis an unweeded garden,
That grows to seed; things rank and gross in nature
Possess it merely. That it should come to this!
But two months dead: nay, not so much, not two:
So excellent a king; that was, to this,
Hyperion to a satyr; so loving to my mother
That he might not beteem the winds of heaven
Visit her face too roughly. Heaven and earth!
Must I remember? why, she would hang on him,
        ... etc</div>
</div>

    <div class="DialogLine">
        <div class="DialogWho">Speaker Below</div>
        <div class="DialogWhat">This should be below the purple area
    </div>
```

As you can see, the floating is totally bogus with small divs.

Comment: how about creating columns? create a wrapper div thats `height:100%; width:[img width];` for the left item and a column that is `height:100%;width:[rest of the page];`.

Comment: You will need to make a container that holds all of the little divs and float that container next to your image.  this will make sure all of your little divs stay together in a column - What he said ^^

Comment: I want the divs to flow under the purple box once they're low enough rather than continue to be offset by the width of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not float the `.DialogLine` and `.DialogAction` elements

Just give them the correct `margin-left` (*equal to the width of the left column*)

And do not forget to give `overflow:hidden` to them as well so the will expand to fit their contents..

```
.DialogAction {
    padding: 50px;
    font-style: italic;
    margin-left:210px;
}
.DialogLine {
    margin-left:210px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Xf9Qv/4/

Comment: Speaker Below is wrong in your example (it should be all the way left) (Hamlet too in your case) and I don't have the ability to know where the first "below" item would start because I won't be controlling the amount of content in the dialog divs. (So I won't be able to just put the margin-left property on the first few items and then leave it off the rest). Also, your lines of text ended up below the speaker instead of out to the right of it (that might be solvable with some fiddling)

Comment: not sure i understand the problem correctly.. based on what logic should something go to the left (*below the image*)? You might want to remove the margins altogether so that the *rows* follow the normal flow.. See http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Xf9Qv/7/